# Terraform state and autoscaling

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, autoscaling

When autoscaling occurs - does the terraform state get updated with the correct count of resources?
If not, will it cause ay issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When autoscaling occurs nothing will automatically update the state to reflect that event. If you do not update the terraform code to reflect the new value, in the next `terraform plan` you will see the state change show up. Which could indeed cause issues.

If you don't need to track the desired capacity outside of the creation of the autoscaling group I would recommend you ignore the [desired_capacity](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group#desired_capacity) argument by using a lifecycle block to [ignore changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes) to the argument.

```
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [ "desired_capacity" ]
}
```